# Virtual method but non-virtual destructor

Tags: c++

I get the error "Class 'Polygon' has virtual method 'area' but non-virtual destructor" in Eclipse CDT. Why? Code snippet:

Header files:

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape();
protected:
    virtual double area() const = 0;
}

class Polygon : public Shape {
    public:  
        ~Polygon();
    protected:
        double area() const;
    private:
        Vertex* vertices; 
}
```

Implementation:

```
Polygon::~Polygon() {delete[] this->vertices;}
double Polygon::area() const {
    ...
    return areaSum;
}
```

Comment: Note: Its a warning not an error. But IMO its one you should take not of and fix.

Comment: @kerrek: yes, virtual destructors ARE inherited.  If a base class destructor is virtual, then all derived destructors are also virtual.  Otherwise you could not delete a derived class instance from a base class pointer via polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know they weren't implicitly virtual.

Comment: What version of (presumably) g++ are you using behind Eclipse?

Comment: It depends on the compiler, apparently.  For instance, in Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero C++ compilers, derived destructors ARE implicitally virtual if the base class destructor is virtual.

Comment: This is nonsense, of course the derived class destructor is virtual, on all compilers. Although now I've written it I'm starting to have doubts. How would you know that a destructor is virtual? The only obvious difference would seem to be whether deleteing a pointer invokes UB or not. That's a pretty subtle test. Just for once I'd like to see a quote from the standard.

Comment: Um, I don't really know. I have installed some kind of cygwin compiler a couple of months ago, maybe its that.

Comment: @Emil: Cygwin is gcc, but really, whatever else, this isn't a compiler specific issue.

Comment: @John:

12.5.7:


A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); if any objects of that class or any
derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined. If a class has a base class with a
virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or implicitly- declared) is virtual.

Comment: @Remy: I don't think your argument works. To delete a derived class via a base class pointer requires the base class destructor to be virtual, not the derived class destructor.

Comment: @MrLunchtime: Thanks, I think that clears it up.

Comment: @MrLunchtime: Ok, so that means I don't need to put a virtual keyword before the destructor in the Polygon class?

Comment: Whoops, very sorry, I got that wrong - I'm deleting the comment!

Comment: @Emil: Yes, that should be fine, from the compiler's point of view.  Stylistically, though, I personally think it's a very good idea to add the "virtual" there for the benefit of any human who is reading your code :)

Comment: @john: read my comment again, I said the base class destructor had to be virtual in order to delete an object using a base class pointer.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a bug in eclipse, or maybe it's a 'style' warning about a minor issue. Polygon does have a virtual destructor automatically because it's base class destructor is virtual.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
class Shape {
public:
  virtual ~Shape() {}
protected:
  virtual double area() const = 0;
}

class Polygon : public Shape {
  public:  
      virtual ~Polygon();
  protected:
      double area() const;
  private:
      Vertex* vertices; 
 }
```

This works for me, for the issue faced!

Comment: why down-casted?